# Good free software that will join .001 files?

Tags: windows-vista

Can any one suggest free PC software that will join .001 files and what is the proper extension name of the files if possible?

Answer (score 5):

[HJ-Split](http://www.freebyte.com/hjsplit/) also will use this type of extension on top of what Dan has already mentioned. It is a free file splitter and joiner.

Comment: +1 for HJSplit is the most commonly used software for this.

Answer (score 4):

In short, use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

[How to extract 001 files?](http://www.binaries4all.com/001/)

Answer (score 2):

Usually those files are part of a split ZIP or RAR file. One of the files in that directory should have the .rar or .zip extension. Use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), [IZArc](http://www.izarc.org/) or [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) to open that file, and you will get the contents of the .001 file.

Comment: i don't think so, splitted RAR archives for example are *.RAR, *.R00, *.R01, *.R02, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[**Total Commander**](http://www.ghisler.com/)

File > Combine Files

[image]

> This function allows to combine
>   multiple files to one big file. Total
>   Commander can not only combine files
>   created with its own function split
>   file, but also files created with the
>   Unix command split -b. Put the cursor
>   on the first partial file and choose
>   'combine files'. The file names must
>   be numbered in ascending order, or
>   have letters in ascending order. Total
>   Commander will detect **file.001**,
>   file.002, file.003, but also fileaa,
>   fileab, fileac etc.

Answer (score 0):

Peazip works nicely for that,never tryed using 7zip for that, but if the How-To Geek says it works, it probably does.