# How to merge/combine files with extensions .001, .002, .003.. etc?

Tags: concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good free software that will join .001 files?](https://superuser.com/questions/36862/good-free-software-that-will-join-001-files)

There are files on sites like rapidshare which have extensions like `.001`, `.002`, `.003`? They seem to be split by some tool. How to merge these files?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/36862/good-free-software-that-will-join-001-files

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The files have likely been split by a compression program. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) should handle them fine. They could also have been split with [hjsplit](http://www.freebyte.com/hjsplit/) or a similar tool, but 7-zip should handle the files.

Comment: 7-Zip all the way.  This utility should automatically be part of any superuser's catalog of tools.  Excellent compression, extensive compatibility, command-line interface, ... +1.

Answer (score 13):

It depends what kind of files they are. [RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) and [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) files often come as multi-part archives which need unarchiving by a suitable utility ([WinRAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR), [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip). etc.).

If the file has been split on the byte level into parts you can use the [unix `cat` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) to combine them again:

```
cat file.jpg.* > fileCombined.jpg
```

Comment: The filenames don't have any indication of what tool was used. For example rar files have something like r01, r02, r03..which is not my case. Unless there's a tool that can identity which tool was used to do the splitting.

Comment: I was having this error "Unexpected end of data" when untar gz because I splitted tar gz a tar gz file. Then I used this answer to combine the splitted files before untar gz again, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Fans of the mighty **[Total Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander)** simply use **Files > Combine Files**.

**[Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGJ3slhPpzs)**

You can also install the **[7-Zip Plugin](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/7zip_plugin.html)** for Total Commander.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the other answers assume that the files are parts of a RAR (or similar) archive.  If, on the other hand, they are simply split files and you want to recombine them, there is a simple way:

On Unix systems, just use `cat` - it's what it was made for - con*cat*enate.  Just `cat foo.001 foo.002 ... > foo.combined` and you're done.

On Windows, the simple, unassuming command line `copy` command can in fact also do this, but you **must** remember the `/B` switch.

Answer (score -1):

You may also be able to re-join them with a parity checking software, such as "QuickPAR" (you can search Google for this application as I believe it is freeware).

You will know if it is a PAR compression / split fileset if the collection of files contains files with ".PAR", or .P01, .P02, etc. file extensions.  In some cases, once you run the PAR files against the compressed fileset, it will merge the files into one file. At the same time, these files will ensure that the files you are using are complete and fully in tact.

This is common among the "Warez Scene", and is often used to obfuscate those who are not "in the know" or "part of the scene" where related to illegally obtained movies, software, music, etc.